# Not being able to build F# type provider SDK

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have finally come across something that no one else seemed to have come across (at least from what I can tell). I trying to build an F# type provider using [TypeProviders.SDK](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK).

As soon as I build the solution I get the error: "FS0810,   Property 'CultureName' cannot be set,   \LemonadeProvider\paket-files\fsprojects\FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK\src\ProvidedTypes.fs" on line 2090 and again at 3162 in the design time project of the solution.

I do not think this is useful but the Test project also fails as it can not find the LemonadeProvider.Runtime.dll. I am assuming this will get created when the Runtime project will build successfully.

PS: As of right now I am just tring to build the provided template, I have not changed the code or added anything to it. Hence I have not attached any code, but please feel free to ask for it.

Comment: How are you building it? VisualStudio, VS Code, command line...? Before anything can build, you need to do 'dotnet tool restore' followed by 'dotnet paket update'. Have you performed these steps?

Comment: I have tried building it on both command line and VisualStudio. And yes, I have completed both the 'dotnet tool restore' and 'dotnet paket update' steps.

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue lied with the ProvidedTypes.fs and ProvidedTypes.fsi files created by the SDK.

The issue was solved for me when I replaced the files with the ones found in '[SDK-dsyme-patch-7](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK/tree/dsyme-patch-7)' which provided compatibility for different .Net environments which was missing from the original SDK. There might be other differences but this is the one I found and it fixed the problem for me.
The files can be found under '/src/' in the dsyme patch.

The code I am referring to is as follows and has been added twice to the ProvidedTypes.fs:

```
#if NETSTANDARD
            asmName.CultureName <- System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Name
    #else
            asmName.CultureInfo <- System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    #endif
            asmName
```

I am not aware if there is a new SDK that has solved the problem. But at the time when the question was asked, this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding issue is https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK/issues/353

### Known workarounds

Change minimum target to net461. Replace all instances of net45 with net461, except for in netfx.props, where you can just delete the lines referencing net45* frameworks (I suspect the removal of those lines isn't strictly speaking necessary).

---

I did this workaround but am now facing these kinds of errors: (like 2000 of them)

> C:\Users\user\source\repos\HelloWorldProvider\paket-files\fsprojects\FSharp.TypeProviders.SDK\src\ProvidedTypes.fs(34,7): error FS0074: The type referenced through 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard'. [C:\Users\user\source\repos\HelloWorldProvider\src\HelloWorldProvider.DesignTime\HelloWorldProvider.DesignTime.fsproj]